# In a react app, where is the best place to kick off the initial API service call for data load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react app, where should the initial API service calls live? Should it live in a component tied to a feature or a separate service component?

How does this work? I'm coming from an angular background. Trying to understand this.

Comment: "Should it live in a component tied to a feature..." What does "feature" mean in this context?

Comment: The [**componentDidMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) hook of a component is a good place to fetch your data. For more intricate shared state, you might want to look at a state library, like [**Redux**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) or [**MobX**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx).

Comment: React is a component based architecture. Make calls from the relevant component or from the topmost component in the hierarchy. Ideally, i would use `componentWillMount` lifecycle callback for such calls.

Comment: If you want to emulate `services` pattern of angular - please read about `redux`. And dont try to emulate angular in react - the concepts and approach is different.

Comment: @Tholle , et. al: So that's an acceptable place to put the this.props.getData() calls? And it's acceptable to tie a REST API call there?

Comment: @chrisjlee Sure. If the API response data will be used by the component and its children only, it is a perfectly valid practice. It will save you from introducing an unnecessary state library.

Comment: If using a Flux architecture for your React app (which I recommend) then you would want to make service calls in your action creators.  There would be a total of three actions, a SERVICE_DISPATCH, SERVICE_SUCCESS and SERVICE_ERROR tied to the the initial request and the async resolution.  Reducers would map the service response to the app state and the React views would map the app state to the DOM.  Components would not need to do anymore more than dispatch the initial request action and the flux framework should take care of the rest.  Consider `react-redux` as a starting point.

Comment: I'm going to disagree slightly with some of the other answers and suggest the `componentWillMount` method, which is fired as your component is about to be rendered. Although, quite honestly, you probably won't see much difference from `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**componentDidMount**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) hook of a component is a good place to fetch your data. For more intricate shared state, you might want to look at a state library, like [**Redux**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) or [**MobX**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx).

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zesoyuwici/edit?js,output))**

```
function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('bar');
  }, 2000));
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: 'foo'
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(data => {
      this.setState({ data });
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.data} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Oh perfect thanks. So this is acceptable even though it couples your component to a Web service call?

Comment: @chrisjlee Yes, it's perfectly fine. It's not suitable for every case imaginable, as discussed in the comments above.